# What is the best way to display a large amount of different information in Android?

Tags: android, database

I am currently creating an app that is a guide for a game which involves the user navigating through categories and a large amount of information being displayed. For instance, if I wanted to review information regarding a specific weapon, I may navigate through Items > Weapons > Ranged > Bow. What would be the best to to set this up so the app would run smoothly? I may have up to 100 of these different items the user can view.

The two current approaches I am considering is either making a local SQL database of all of these items, and then having one activity that pulls from the database based on what the user selects. The other being to just make string resources and then load those resources depending on what item the user selects. Any opinions or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: i handled my problem by storing data in sqlite and then retrieving them through multiple async tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about string resources but if you are doing "read only" operations on the data and not saving any user input I would suggest NOT using SQLite. The problem with SQLite for this use is that you will have to create the tables and populate the database programmatically the first time that the app is run. (someone correct me if there is another way to do this) Basically you will end up writing all of your information as strings or reading it from a file on the device anyway, it will just get inserted into the database and be accessed from there every time after. Another drawback is that every time you want to update the information in the app you will have to add rules in the "onUpgrade" method of the database handler. Accessing the data from SQLite will be faster than reading files but IMHO it is a way bigger pain than it is worth for just read operations (unless you have massive amounts of data.. "massive" in the computer world happens to be pretty darn big).

I would probably store the data in your own files (XML, JSON, or just plain text) and put it in the assets folder. Using a nice folder structure and good file naming in there would allow you to add new information without having to change your program.

Another option is to build a web database, pull the information from there, and save it to the local SQLite database when there is an update to the information that you saved online. This makes it easy for you to make revisions to the content without having to send out an app update but takes quite a bit more work

Answer (score 0):

[The Content Provider](https://github.com/BoD/android-contentprovider-generator) is the prefered [way to store big data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) on the android platform and fortunately many [tools are](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/111) available to do the hard work for [you.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) With [that](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) said [I would](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) hardly consider 100 a large amount of data even on a mobile device. Will the data change? In other words is it static or dynamic? I recommend the Content provider but you could use shared preferences, a resource file or even hard code your values.

Comment: It is likely the data will change. However, whenever a user selects an item I would like a full page to be displayed for that item. Basically what I'm looking for is an approach so I don't need to make a separate activity for each item to have it displayed, and instead use one activity to dynamically load information on whichever item the user selects